# ATmega328p driving RGB LED WS2801

Tags: led, atmega, rgb

I am using an ATmega328p to control [this](http://www.avc-shop.de/WS2801-digitales-LED-RGB-Modul-IP65-vergossen-4-LEDs/Modul) RGB LED module.  The ATmega is on an Arduino Uno, but I am programming it in C, *without* using the Arduino libraries.

To power the RGB module I am also using a 12V power supply.
To power the Arudino Uno I am using the USB power.
I connected it the following way:

- **RGB LED Module** 12V -> **12V power supply** 12V
- **RGB LED Module** GND -> **12V power supply** GND
- **RGB LED Module** SDI -> **ATmega** PORTB0
- **RGB LED Module** SCK -> **ATmega** PORTB1
- **RGB LED Module** GND -> **ATmega** GND

Now if I send some data R=0xFF, G=0xFF, B=0xFF (Set SDI to 5V and make every second 24 SCK pulses) according to [the datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2801.pdf) nothing happens.
The lights stay off.
But randomly I found out, that if I disconnect the 12V power supply and connected it again randomly, sometimes the Lights turning on in a random color.
So I don't have any clue whats going on.

What can cause this behavior, what can I do to find the error?

[image]

```
    #include <avr/io.h>


// 16ms delay.
static void delShort()
{
    TCCR0B = 0;
    TCCR0A = 0;
    TIMSK0 = 0;
    TCNT0 = 0;
    GTCCR = 0;

    TIFR0 = TIFR0 | (1 << TOV0);
    TCCR0B = (1 << CS02) | (1 << CS00);

    while(!(TIFR0 & (1 << TOV0)))
    {

    }

    TCCR0B = 0;
}

// 1000ms delay.
static void delLong()
{
    for(unsigned char lI = 0; lI < 61; ++lI)
    {
        delShort();
    }
}

static void ledSetup()
{
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB0);
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB0);

    PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB1);
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB1);
}

static void ledWrite(uint32_t pData)
{
    uint32_t lValue = pData;

    for(uint8_t lIndex = 0; lIndex < 24; ++lIndex)
    {
        if(lValue & 0x1)
        {
            PORTB |= (1 << PORTB0);
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB0);
        }

        delShort();

        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB1);

        delShort();

        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB1);

        delShort();

        lValue = lValue >> 1;
    }
}


void main(void)
{
    ledSetup();

    delLong();

    while (1) 
    {
        delLong();
        ledWrite(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
}
```

Comment: Schematic and the code are needed.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I added the code and schematic.

Comment: @Michael Oh, wow! It's been some years since I was drawing ASCII schematics!! Cool. (I actually wrote a program to accept LTSpice schematics and then generate quite readable ASCII from that.) Just so you know, there is a schematic editor available here for you and you can construct arbitrary "black boxes" with arbitrary pin names, if you want to. It's not so bad.

Comment: As you are developing for an ATmega in C without using the Arduino libraries or approach, I've edited your question to emphasize that, and de-emphasize the nearly irrelevant fact that your board happens to say "Arduino" on it.

Comment: You should verify that your timing functions work for sure as a first step.

Comment: _"But randomly I found out, that if I disconnect the 12V power supply and connected it again randomly, sometimes the Lights turning on in a random color."_ - How long between the disconnect and reconnect? Perhaps some caps aren't fully discharging, leaving some things in a "half running" state...

Comment: The link to the module does not bring anything specific. Please provide a datasheet to the modules. Also, from the signal names you can assume it is I2C driven device. How the I2C is implemented in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The chip timings are in nanoseconds, not milliseconds, so you only have a few cycles between bits, definitely not enough that you need a timer. The long delay between bits resets the devices after each bit, so the next bit is again interpreted as the first bit of a block.

I'd use a few consecutive

```
asm volatile ("nop");
```

as delays, seven should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an example first?
Just to eliminate the possibility of a wiring problem.

I suggest trying this library: Adafruit-WS2801-Library

[WS2801 Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-WS2801-Library)

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. FYI: Answers that are purely links are frowned upon, as links often go dead or the content changes.

Comment: I tried the example using the library but it's not working. So I think it's a hardware problem.

Comment: You're right Bort, I added the library name in case the link goes down.

Comment: This might be more a comment-class suggestion than an answer.  But regardless, the fact that it doesn't work suggests that the hardware issues preventing the presumed-good library from working should be addressed before worrying about why the custom code does not work.